# Installing Compiler for Matlab 2012a on Windows10

Tags: matlab, mex

I have to run some mex files, But Matlab shows no compiler or SDK installed. So i tried to install Windows SDK 7.1. But It gives following error

[image: Error]

I have Windows10 system, So I can't uninstall .NET Framework 4 as suggested in many solutions on web search.

Any Ideas to resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you need to compile mex files or just run them?

Comment: I am trying to install Libsvm library [link](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) which include mex files.

Comment: @Dharmendra I've been through this on a Windows machine on which I had to run LibSVM. Indeed I can confirm that you need to install (in this order) NET Framework 4, Windows SDK and then run `mex -setup` on Matlab. Matlab will show you the Windows SDK compiler which you can configure as default for `mex` files and then you can compile LibSVM.